# Repeated log statements in EC2 syslog

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

In my EC2 instance, syslog I am seeing a lot of:

```
Aug 19 07:42:01 ip-172-31-0-40 CRON[6465]: (root) CMD (/var/awslogs/bin/awslogs-nanny.sh > /dev/null 2>&1)
```

type statements getting printed in the Cloudwatch logs (more than a few dozen per second). Is there any way to turn this off and give only minimal log messages ?

Answer (score 0):

That log line is generated by the cron daemon itself  it writes to syslog by default on some distros. How to change this behavior is also dependent but for example the top answer for  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212355/where-is-my-logfile-of-crontab  explains how configure cron to have its own log file on Debian based systems. This would stop the messages flooding your syslog

Comment: I am using ubuntu (so yes based on Debian). I realised that cron is bombarding the syslog but the solution in that link did not work for me. Even when I added `cron.* /var/log/cron.log` to my /etc/rsyslog.conf (and machine restarted after that) the syslog was bombarded with the CRON related messages